# Is there any other jurisdiction where a government-devised scheme similar to civil forfeiture for crime prevention exist other than the U.S.?

Tags: united-states, international, due-process, civil-rights

In the U.S., many states adopted laws that allow law enforcement to appropriate property that is liquid or easily liquidated (in practice predominantly cash) not only in cases where past criminal activity has been found substantially likely by law enforcement and confiscation is done to initiate criminal prosecution, but even when (1) there would be no such prosecution (or if there was and a case was closed the confiscated property would not be returned) and even in cases where (2) there is only a suspicion of future criminal activity.

Is there any state in the Western world that allows for either one of the two or both situations?

Are there better arguments to this ploy in the U.S. today than the sovereign citizen-equivalent arguments that the property is the defendant (Haha!) and not a person so due process doesn’t apply?

Comment: upvote for the word "scheme"

Comment: "*appropriate property of currency attributes*" I think this is an editing error, but I am not sure what was intended, so i am not editing to correct. Also, automobiles are sized quite often, perhaps almost as often as cash (I have not accurate statistics at hand). See also ["Supreme Court Limits Police Powers to Seize Private Property"](https://www.nytimes.com/2019/02/20/us/politics/civil-asset-forfeiture-supreme-court.html) from the NY Times Feb. 20, 2019

Comment: Oh, wow! My understanding was that only things that you can use as liquid assets can be subject to this, or at least in cases of the alleged suspicion of future use for illicit means. (Also, good direction with the U.S. Supreme Court)

Comment: I'm not sure if the last argument is asking for arguments legally justifying the practice, the idea is that property is indeed not a person so it doesn't have rights.  That's why it's a civil proceeding to fight rather than a criminal defense.

Comment: Neither does it have legal capacity to be held civilly or criminally liable for anything under any sane argument. Maybe we should rethink capital cases and send the smoking gun in the electrocution room, no?

Comment: In theory it's supposed to be reserved for cases where there is some cash or item that was probably part of a crime but the state doesn't know who owns it.  For example, if the police raid a stash house and find piles of cash next to drugs, none of the people inside the house will probably claim the cash is theirs, so there's no particular person's criminal trial to tie the cash to.  The problem is mainly when it's used against property that has a clear owner and held independently of any criminal prosecution against them.

Comment: @IllusiveBrian Curent law says tht when property is "used in a crime" it is subject to forfieture. So if a person delivers drugs, a car may be forfiet. Worse yet, people who drive to red light districts ro solicit a prostitute have been hit with forfeiture of their vehicles. I think civil forfeiture as it now exists in the US is unjust and out of control, and violates some constitutional protections, but I am not a Justice nor a member of Congress. There is lots of pressure to keep it in place.

Comment: I would still like to know what is meant by "*appropriate property of currency attributes*" in the question.

Comment: Maybe liquid assets or assets that can easily take the function of liquid assets (for e.g. jewelry). If confiscatin property is weighted against social factors of the individual, the seriousness of a crime, the probability that the confiscation would be prohibitive in the commission of the crime, and such factors, and it would be a prerequisite to at least initiate criminal prosecution at any level of government, and release it unless they are on-going or result in incarceration but taking without proceedings, and not weighing social factors is outrageous.

Comment: Confiscating a car in a prostitute situation is also bogus, you can solicit on the street, confiscation would not be prohibitive just merely impeding which is the a disproportionately harsh measure against one who only has that as means of transit especially in cases where a crime is not suspected to have been committed just merely to be committed in the future.

Comment: @DavidSiegel Fair?

Comment: If you are saying that is what the law **should** be, you have a reasonable point. If you are saying that is what US law now is, I am fairly sure that you are incorrect. US law doesn't limit forfeiture to cash or things easily sold for cash. It does not limit   forfeiture  to thins that would be "prohibitive" that is where forfeiture would help prevent a future crime. Neither of those is relevant at all.If the property was "used in a crime" even incidentally, or acquired by crime, including purchased with the proceeds of crime, it is subject to forfeiture and no crime must be charged. [...]

Comment: [...] I hope to give an actual answer soon.

Comment: @DavidSiegel I agree the current policy is heinously unjust and unconstitutional, I'm just trying to explain the rationale behind the rule.  In my opinion something like a car or possessions on someone's person, in their car, etc should not be subject to civil asset forfeiture, it should only apply where there's a clear inability of the state to know who a particular asset they seize belongs to.  In the system I think it should move toward it would never apply to a properly registered car because there's a clear owner.

Comment: @IllusiveBrian "*In theory it's supposed to be reserved for cases where there is some cash or item that was probably part of a crime but the state doesn't know who owns it.*" Where is that theory spelled out? Not in any US law or court opinion that I know of. Who propounded it? Or is this theory your view of what the law should be?

Comment: @DavidSiegel I was talking about the origin, although I just checked again and realized I misunderstood the reasoning, it looks like it was for customs enforcement on ships where the owner was in another country.  My misunderstanding was that I thought it was for cases where there was smuggled cargo no one would take ownership of once it was found.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, in [england-and-wales](/questions/tagged/england-and-wales) the [Criminal Finances Act 2017](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2017/22/part/1/chapter/1/crossheading/unexplained-wealth-orders-england-and-wales-and-northern-ireland/enacted) introduced 'Unexplained Wealth Orders', which compel the respondent to provide a statement:

> - (a) setting out the nature and extent of the respondent’s interest in the property in respect of which the order is made,
> - (b) explaining how the respondent obtained the property (including, in particular, how any costs incurred in obtaining it were met),
> - (c) where the property is held by the trustees of a settlement, setting out such details of the settlement as may be specified in the
>   order, and
> - (d) setting out such other information in connection with the property as may be so specified.

There a few requirements set out in section 362B, for example, the property must have value of over £50,000; there should be "reasonable grounds" for suspicion that the respondent would have been unable to obtain the property using their lawfully obtained income; the respondent or their connections must have either been involved in serious or organised crime, or be a politically exposed person, and so on.

If the respondent refuses to make such a statement, the police may apply for a Civil Recovery Order to confiscate the property, with the property in question "presumed to be recoverable property" (section 362C(2)). Giving false information in such a statement is a criminal offence.

Answer (score 3):

[british-columbia](/questions/tagged/british-columbia)

British Columbia has a civil forfeiture regime governed by the [*Civil Forfeiture Act*](https://www.bclaws.gov.bc.ca/civix/document/id/complete/statreg/05029_01).

It establishes an office called the "director" of civil forfeiture. The director can apply to the court for orders forfeiting to the government property that was the proceeds of or the instrument of unlawful activity.

Findings are "to be made on the balance of probabilities."

Answer (score 2):

### Yes

[australia](/questions/tagged/australia)

The Commonwealth and all states and territories have [Proceeds of Crime](http://www6.austlii.edu.au/cgi-bin/viewdb/au/legis/cth/consol_act/poca2002160/) legislation. Under these acts, the government can confiscate:

> benefits derived from breaking the law,
>
> money made from writing or having film or television shows made about how you broke the law,
>
> unexplained wealth that you can’t prove was obtained legally,
>
> as a punishment.

Further there is a Council of Europe Convention on Laundering, Search, Seizure and Confiscation of the Proceeds from Crime and the Commonwealth’s law was enacted to actuate Australia’s obligations under that Convention and other treaties.

Comment: Is this really a yes and not a “no”

Comment: The prerequisites in these jurisdictions if as described, dont seem outrageous or even seem reasonable. The issue in the question is such appropriation on the suspicion of future crime without a bar of at least the preponderance of the evidence or rather higher given the cop is not a judge nor would he conduct a full adversarial proceeding on the street, and their decision on provisionally lying on the premise a crime would be committed can very well be in complete disproportion, and if (when) exploited can be used to weaponize the fists of the executive branch against political adversaries

Comment: [...] and members of protected social groups.

Answer (score 2):

There are states where money can be seized simply because the owner gives no plausible explanation of the source, with no requirement for the prosecution to show any connection between the money and a crime, e.g. [Italy](https://www.osce.org/files/f/documents/b/0/93412.pdf). AFAIK the prosecution still has to show an organized crime connection, but they do not have to suggest any connection between the money and the crime, as long as the money is disproportionate to the legal economic activity of the owner.

Comment: Interesting you specifically bring up Italy; I remember when Mario Balotelli was pulled over with ca. €100,000 or maybe even half a mill in his trunk, and the cops asked why he has so much money on him, and he said because he can. And, of course, they didn’t confiscated his legally earned money. This does not contradict what you described by any means, it was just a fun fact I actually happened to have think of as a perfect counter example I had in mind drafting this question. That even in such flagrantly excessive amounts of explanations did not trigger similar action in the Italy in the EU.

Comment: Interestingly enough, it could still happen although probably still not as outrageously as in some U.S. examples.

Comment: @kisspuska, if that had gone to court he could have pointed to *legitimate* earnings which presumably make 100 grand look like small change. That's what the law was about.

Comment: Sorry, I just looked the story up as a reminder for myself (it was a good ten years ago) he only had — literally change in a top class player like him — change: 5,000 and pound sterlings it appears. (He also said, "Because I'm rich!" lol Love the guy)